# Python-Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

I was wondering if there are ways that i can crawl twitter without using their API? I tried using their API and it was awesome. However i would like to ask if there is any alternative? As the crawler i am working on will be pass around, i do not wish for my token keys to be shared among them. Neither do i want everyone of them to go through the hassle of creating a Dev account so on and so fore.

The crawler i created with twitter API is capable of retrieving many many tweets. And the crawler i created without was only able to crawl around 10, as other tweets would be outside of the html.

I am using python 3.6

```
def spider(targetname, DOMAIN):
for item in g_data:
    try:
        name = item.find_all("strong", {"class": "fullname show-popup-with-id "})[0].text
        username = item.find_all("span", {"class": "username u-dir"})[0].text
        post = item.find_all("p", {"class": "TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text"})[0].text
        retweetby = item.find_all("a", {"href": "/"+targetname})[0].text
        subdatas = item.find_all('div', {'class':'ProfileTweet-actionCountList u-hiddenVisually'})
        for subdata in subdatas:
            replies = subdata.find_all("span", {"class": "ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria"})[0].text
            retweets = subdata.find_all("span", {"class": "ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria"})[1].text
            likes = subdata.find_all("span", {"class": "ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria"})[2].text
        datas = item.find_all('a', {'class':'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'})
        for data in datas:
            link = DOMAIN + data['href']
            date = data['title']
        if link in open(crawledfile).read():
            pass
        else:
            append_to_crawled(crawledfile, name, username, post, link, replies, retweets, likes, retweetby, date)
        output(name, username, post, link, replies, retweets, likes, retweetby, date)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: NO WAY , to bypass twitter's API.

Comment: post the code for your crawler without the twitter API

Comment: @MrSam well, you can use Selenium and PhantomJS.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37967778/5283213

Comment: Hi @TheDarkKnight i have posted the part that is doing the crawling. Mind taking a look?

Comment: I think [`https://mobile.twitter.com`](https://mobile.twitter.com) is a good place to crawl the twitter data. I have wrote some [code](https://github.com/stamaimer/MrUirf/blob/master/twitter/gen_friendship.py) to generate friendship from this website.

Comment: Hi @stamaimer do you have any documentations to your code?

Comment: @NewbieCoder I'll write some documentations later.

Answer (score 0):

There ***is*** a way to crawl/ `scrape` twitter without using the twitter API; however, ***it is highly recommended that you use the API itself***. This has several advantages, such as ***it being official***, in addition to having a ton of support from the community.

Nevertheless, you can perform crawling using `requests` and `beautiful soup`, or if you're looking for a more powerful option, go for `Selenium` and `PhantomJS`.

Here are a couple of similar questions that you can read through:

[Scraping of the Twitter follower page using selenium and phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43983874/5283213)

[How to collect tweets about an event that are posted on specific date using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44303555/5283213)

[How to perform oauth when doing twitter scraping with python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308634/5283213)

[Infinite Web Scraping Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37967778/5283213)

Cheers :)